# Related Rates of Change - Cylinder Question

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

A cylindrical tank with radius 5 cm is being filled with water at rate of 3 cm^3 per min. how fast is the height of the water increasing?

I dont want this question solved, but please help me correct my working out:

- radius = 5
- dv/dt =  3
- dh/dt = dh/dv * dv/dt
- v=(pi)(r^2)(h)

because r is constant you could write: V=(pi)(5^2)(h) and then find the derivative...

but is there an alternate method where we can derive dv/dh without first substituting r=5??

Comment: there is no other way. And second $\frac{dv}{dh}$ is expressed in cm, not m. Therefore, r would be 500 cm.

Comment: apologies, it was supposed to read 5cm ... oh okay, is there a way you could re-write r in terms of H?

Comment: no, because r is constant, you cannot use derivatives to find $\frac{dh}{dt}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no other way to find $\frac{dv}{dh}$ without substituting $r = 5$.

To solve the question:

$$V = \pi r^2h$$

Since r is constant:
$$V = \pi 25h$$
$$\frac{dV}{dt} = 25 \pi*\frac{dh}{dt}$$
$$3 = 25 \pi*\frac{dh}{dt}$$
$$\frac{dh}{dt} = \frac{3}{25\pi} \text{cm/min}$$

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to solve this problem, though you will still ultimately substitute the known value of the radius.  Implicitly differentiate the equation with respect to time (remembering to apply the product rule):

$$V = \pi r^2h$$
$$\frac {dV}{dt} = \pi (2r \frac {dr}{dt}h + r^2 \frac {dh}{dt})$$

Since the rate of change of the radius with respect to time $(\frac {dr}{dt})$ is zero (i.e., the radius is not changing therefore its rate of change is zero), the first term in the parentheses disappears:
$$\frac {dV}{dt} = \pi (0 + r^2 \frac {dh}{dt})$$
$$\frac {dV}{dt} = \pi r^2 \frac {dh}{dt}$$

Substituting known values,
$$3 = \pi 5^2 \frac {dh}{dt}$$
$$\frac {3}{25 \pi} = \frac {dh}{dt}$$

However, substituting the known, constant value into the equation early allows you to avoid application of the product rule.  This is why you want to substitute known constants into the equation before you differentiate.

Comment: Although this way of solving the problem is a bit more complicated, it shows a good example of how to work through any related rates problem.  Here's a link to a site that shows a pretty in depth explanation of solving this problem this way: https://jakesmathlessons.com/derivatives/related-rates-cylinder-problem/